# NSJSONSerialization data in a different format

Tags: ios, json, parsing, parse-platform, nsjsonserialization

I am using Parse.com as a backend of my application, where I am currently storing the data there.

The data is a list of video game consoles. I was able to make an output of it, but instead of JSON data, the output is a big NSMutableArray.

This is my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Consoles"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"APPLICATION_ID" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
    [request setValue:@"REST_API_KEY" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];

    NSError *error;

    id listOfConsoles = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

    NSLog(@"The list: %@", listOfConsoles);
}
```

The output:

```
The list: {
    results =     (
                {
            createdAt = "2013-03-21T07:26:04.149Z";
            name = PlayStation;
            objectId = vloIK0MZIA;
            updatedAt = "2013-03-21T07:26:04.149Z";
        },
                {
            createdAt = "2013-03-21T07:26:34.209Z";
            name = Wii;
            objectId = RIRpgbznlq;
            updatedAt = "2013-03-21T07:26:34.209Z";
        },
                {
            createdAt = "2013-03-21T07:26:39.391Z";
            name = Xbox;
            objectId = xBNgHtJbrV;
            updatedAt = "2013-03-21T07:26:39.391Z";
        }
    );
}
```

What I want the output to be:

```
{
  "results" : [
    {
      "objectId" : "vloIK0MZIA",
      "updatedAt" : "2013-03-21T07:26:04.149Z",
      "createdAt" : "2013-03-21T07:26:04.149Z",
      "name" : "PlayStation"
    },
    {
      "objectId" : "RIRpgbznlq",
      "updatedAt" : "2013-03-21T07:26:34.209Z",
      "createdAt" : "2013-03-21T07:26:34.209Z",
      "name" : "Wii"
    },
    {
      "objectId" : "xBNgHtJbrV",
      "updatedAt" : "2013-03-21T07:26:39.391Z",
      "createdAt" : "2013-03-21T07:26:39.391Z",
      "name" : "Xbox"
    }
  ]
}
```

**BY THE WAY**

Why is it that when I have a separate **NSData** in the code:

`NSData *JSONData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];`

And change my **NSJSONSerialization** to:

`id listOfConsoles = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];`

The output will be:

```
The list: {
    error = unauthorized;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using Parse's iOS SDK?

Comment: Nothing in particular. I just ran across with Parse.com recently, and on my way using its SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first list is a `NSDictionary` with a single key called "results" which has an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`.

The second list is the same thing..

**Edit 1.0:**

Just to clarify, the second output is JSON, ok? Simply as that, just check [here](http://jsonlint.com/) and validate yourself. The first one is the outputted JSON that is inside an `NSObject`. Of course there will be slight differences...

Comment: I see, but how come the first output is not the same as the second? How will I achieve the second output?

Comment: You are relying on the `NSLog`, and not in what you know it will be there. I can give you an example: I know by heart, that a JSON service I have is returning strings like this "1233". The thing is that after the `NSJSONSerialization`I have `NSNumbers` instead of `NSStrings`.. So I just do `stringValue`, and that's it...

Comment: As a precautionary step, I do copy the result and paste it to an online JSON validator and check if the JSON is correct or not. The 1st one is not, however the second one is.

Comment: That's normal... It was `NSLog`ged... -.-

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that;)

Answer (score 0):

Your Authentication not done successfully. Please check **APPLICATION_ID** and **REST_API_KEY** values.

Comment: If the authentication is not successful, why did I have the first output?

Comment: please tell me exact step when you get response and when you get list: {
    error = unauthorized;
}

Comment: I will get an `error = unauthorized` if I have a separate line for **NSData** and manually called it inside **NSJSONSerialization**. However, I can generate an output if I won't have a separate line for **NSData**.

Answer (score 0):

I was an idiot. I never realized that I tried to convert the JSON to something else, when I wanted the JSON data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Consoles"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setValue:@"APPLICATION_ID" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
    [request setValue:@"REST_API_KEY" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-REST-API-Key"];

    NSString *listOfConsoles = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", listOfConsoles);
}
```